# viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener , onGlobalLayout , infinte loop

Tags: android

I am using  `viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener` , `onGlobalLayout` on the parent view of two text views in order to get width of one and height of the other

```
 private int row_height;
private int column_width;
private RelativeLayout RL;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView33);
    final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView25);
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = RL.getViewTreeObserver();
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            column_width = textView2.getWidth();
            row_height = textView.getHeight();
            textView.setText("column_width" + column_width + "\nrow_height" + row_height);
            CreateEvent(0, 6, 4);
            CreateEvent(0, 8, 6);
            CreateEvent(0, 7, 7);
            CreateEvent(0, 5, 2);
        }
    });

    //CreateEvent(0,6,4); //not working
}
```

The problem is `CreateEvent` is being called for infinite times which slows my app so how solve this?

What I want to do is when the layout is completely shown I save the width of `textView25` and height of `textView33` to use them inside `CreateEvent` and they changes only if layout changes like from `portrait` to `landscape`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the listener as soon as you receive a callback -

```
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        //Add this line
        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        column_width = textView2.getWidth();
        row_height = textView.getHeight();
        textView.setText("column_width" + column_width + "\nrow_height" + row_height);
        CreateEvent(0, 6, 4);
        CreateEvent(0, 8, 6);
        CreateEvent(0, 7, 7);
        CreateEvent(0, 5, 2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Error: This ViewTreeObserver is not alive, call getViewTreeObserver() again

Comment: then call it again - `RL.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);`

Comment: This doesn't work.  It gives the error that Atef Hares mentioned.  Calling it again just gives the same error, assuming you caught the first and the app didn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  I tried to remove the OnGlobalLayoutListener directly from the ViewTreeObserver object, as one other answerer suggested, but it was giving an error.  Finally, I grabbed the tree observer from the view and removed the OnGlobalLayoutListener from that, like this:

```
private class GLListener implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener
{
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout()
    {
        adView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(glListener);  //or "this"
        /*
         *CODE HERE RUNS ONCE
         */
    }
}
```

GLListener is a class that I instantiated and added as the OnGlobalLayoutListener object to adView, which is (as you may have guessed), an AdView.  I did that so I wouldn't have a nested class.  You can make it anonymous.  Either way, the use of "this" works instead of the object reference like I did.